# change the value in Hook onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a customized Hook to change the state of the of a use state variable from true to false, and i want to change it on the onclick of a button to show and hide a div, how can this be done?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useOpenFiltersHook = (): boolean => {
  const [showFilter, setShowFilter] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleShowFilter(): void {
      setShowFilter(true);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);
    handleShowFilter();

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);
  }, []);
  return showFilter;
};
```

```
 const showFilter = useOpenFiltersHook();
{showFilter && (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => !showFilter}>
            <div>Show filter</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
```

Comment: what do you seek to achieve with the resize event listener? It's not so clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type TOpenFilterHook = {
  showFilter: boolean;
  setShowFilter: any;
}

export const useOpenFiltersHook = (): TOpenFilterHook => {
  const [showFilter, setShowFilter] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleShowFilter(): void {
      setShowFilter(true);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);
    handleShowFilter();

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);
  }, []);
  return { showFilter, setShowFilter };
};


... ... ...

const { showFilter, setShowFilter } = useOpenFiltersHook();
  {showFilter && (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowFilter(false)}>
        <div>Show filter</div>
      </button>
    </div>
  )}
```

Comment: And what will be the return type of the hook instead of boolean?

Comment: As you can see, the return type of the hook is the `object` which contains 2 elements. (`showFilter`, `setShowFilter`)

Comment: is it better to be a store not a hook?

Comment: @NewDev,what do you mean?

Comment: i mean that i want to use it in different pages to check its state to show or hide elements

Comment: of course, you can use this `hook` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, one last question: how this line will be now? `const { showFilter, setShowFilter } = useOpenFiltersHook();`

Comment: That line won't be changed.

Comment: i got this error **Property 'setShowFilter' does not exist on type '{}'.**

Comment: I have updated the `return type` of the hook in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Return `setShowFilter` from your hook and call that in `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

I update answer of Bikas Lin. Mostly it is correct but have few issues.

Function declaration shouldn't be there. And currently it will always be opened after initialization, so better approach will be:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useOpenFiltersHook = (isOpened): boolean => {
  const [showFilter, setShowFilter] = useState(isOpened);

  function handleShowFilter(): void {
    setShowFilter(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);
  }, []);
  return { showFilter, setShowFilter };
};
```

So now you can set whether you want it to be initially shown or not.
You can also include toggle logic into your hook, so you wouldn't need to to do it in all of your components. Depending on your situation you can just return toggle function instead of setShowFilter, or add it as a third property.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a way to update state in react

```
 <button onClick={() => !showFilter}>
```

Instead return the state update function from your custom hook

```
export const useOpenFiltersHook = (): boolean => {
  const [showFilter, setShowFilter] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleShowFilter(): void {
      setShowFilter(true);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);
    handleShowFilter();

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleShowFilter);
  }, []);
  return { showFilter, setShowFilter };
};
```

Now you can access the set state function in your component by

```
 const {showFilter, setShowFilter } = useOpenFiltersHook();
{showFilter && (
        <div>
          <button onClick={setShowFilter((previousState)=> return !previousState)}>
            <div>Show filter</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
```